# How to say "I am doing both" in japanese (To say, I am BOTH studying and working at the same time)?

Tags: grammar, particles

so I am enrolled in a work-study program and I want to be able to say " I am both studying and working at the same time"

My take is the following : わたし は べんきょうして も はたらいています. (I am using the て form since it's what I am doing at the moment). I do not know if も is the correct particle to use in this case.

Is this the correct translation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say

> [私]{わたし}は[勉強]{べんきょう}も[仕事]{しごと}もしています。
> *lit.* I am doing both study and work.

AもBもする means "do both A and B".

([勉強]{べんきょう}しても~~ would mean "even though I study~~")

or maybe...

> 私は勉強しながら[働]{はたら}いています。/
> 私は働きながら勉強しています。

verb in continuative form + ながら means "while doing~~".

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! So if I've understood here before ながら, we should drop the ます ?

Comment: @vestalv, yes, ながら is attached to pre-ます form, eg あるき＋ながら, たべ+ながら, み+ながら.

Comment: I wonder what you would do for non-suru verbs?

Comment: @user3856370 That'd be a bit ややこしい... 「VることもVることもしています」「VてもVてもいます」 are grammatical, but I'd rather use VながらVています instead.